# Jquery UI tabs Hash Replace

Tags: jquery, hash

How do i replace `[b]#[/b]` with `[b]?[/b]`, so that it would be http://site.com/?first
Is it even possible?

I have the following script:

```
$(function () {
  var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
  tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '[b][b]#[/b][/b]first';

    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
  });

  $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
});

    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tabNavigation">
            <a href="#first" class="selected">First</a>
            <a href="#second" class="">Second</a>
            <a href="#third" class="">Third</a>
        </ul>
        <div id="first" style="display: block;">
            <h2>First</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="second" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Second</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="third" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Third</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this exactly?  Is it just a visual change?

Comment: @ Explosion Pills - Correct!

Comment: You can only do this with the history API that is not supported by all browsers, such as `history.pushState({}, '?' + window.location.hash);`

Comment: Would that be something you would do with apache? That is if you're even using an apache server.

Comment: not sure if it has to do with URLrewrite :D

Comment: So safely, it's not possible, correct? It's just to make it look nicer